# How to Take Just Data Without Column Names in NodeJS with MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

When I want to take data from mysql in NodeJS, it results like

```
RowDataPacket {  name :  'John',  marks :  56}
```

But I want to take this data without column names or other things. I need to use just NodeJS for this problem. I saw some JSON solutions but I can’t do this cause of my program.

Answer (score 2):

The result of a 'SELECT' query will be an array of objects. And each object defines a row. 
You can either iterate through the array and use the key to access its value like `results.forEach( row => { row[key] })` 
or if your result returns a single row, then you can access the object as `results[0]`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an index and then obtain the value.

For example if you are storing your response in a variable called results.

Use the following:

```
x = results[0].name;
```

Then you can use this variable/name further in your program.